# Symfony2 multiple entity in one form with file upload

Tags: forms, symfony, multiple-tables

I know there are lots of questions about this topic, but this time I'm not asking for code but for an opinion.

I've an entity A that has one-to-many relationship with entities B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J.
When I want to create new data of A I need to put text in some inputs, upload a file and create new data in B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I and J because of the relationship.

In addition, some of the data of the other entities that are not A, proceed from other entities related to B, C, D... like K, L, M, N, O.

I want to construct only one form to collect all data, and I've seen that it can be done through *collections* and *embedded forms*, but it seems so complicated with this amount of entities.

My question is: is there an **easy way** to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You won't like the answer but if you need one form that allows you to add/edit multiple instances of B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J in one shot then collections are really your only approach.  However you do it, your user interface will be cluttered.  That may be okay if your application focuses on data entry speed over usability.  If not then break the form into multiple forms.  The casual user will thank you.